# Showing labels from the map service

Tags: map-service, feature-service

I am using a feature service to show data on the map like so:

```
var featureTableLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://12.122.105.741/arcgis/rest/services/test/FeatureServer/1", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    showLabels: true,
    visible: true,
    syncSelection: true,
    zoomToSelection: true,
    outFields: [ "objectid", "mesto_sifra", "mesto_ime", "ulica_ime", "ime_na_ulica_opstina", "novo_ime_na_ulica", "zabeleska_opstina"],
                    id: "streetsLayer"  });
    map.addLayers([featureTableLayer]);
```

I also have a map service where I have labels

```
var mapLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://12.122.105.741/arcgis/rest/services/test/MapServer/1", {
    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
    showLabels: true,
    visible: true,
    syncSelection: true,
    zoomToSelection: true,
    outFields: [ "objectid", "mesto_sifra", "mesto_ime", "ulica_ime", "ime_na_ulica_opstina", "novo_ime_na_ulica", "zabeleska_opstina"],
                    id: "streetsLayer"  });
    map.addLayers([mapLayer]);
```

I am adding both layers to the map, both the feature and map services but I am not seeing the labels on the map but when I open the map service via the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer it loads the map with the labels. What could be the issue?

[image: labels showing in the ArcGIS Online Map Viewer - Map service]